# Possible bug with `ListContourPlot3D`: Mixed up `PerformanceGoal` labels (for small data?)

Tags: plotting, graphics

I would expect the "Quality" option to give the second result here, which has more polygons and seems to be the better approximation of the implied level surface obtained by trilinear interpolation of the data. This is what `ListContourPlot3D` claims to do:

> ListContourPlot3D linearly interpolates values to give smooth contours.

[image]

Code:

```
data = 1. Table[{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, 3];
contour = 0.884`;
ListContourPlot3D[data, Contours -> {contour}, 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
ListContourPlot3D[data, Contours -> {contour}, 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]
```

IMO, the plot that this should approximate is the piecewise linear (here trilinear because it's 3D data) interpolation of the data, i.e.

```
idata = MapIndexed[#2~List~#1 &, data, {ArrayDepth@data}]~Level~{-3}
f = Interpolation[idata, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
ContourPlot3D[f[x, y, z], {x, 1, 3}, {y, 1, 3}, {z, 1, 3}, 
 Contours -> {contour}]
```

[image]

and this is what the `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"` variant seems to do.

**Aside**

Confusingly, the 2d variant `ListContourPlot` never even tries to show the bilinearly interpolated function, it only ever linearly interpolates on the edges of the uniform grid (kind of like a 2d marching cubes):

[image]

Comment: It should also be noted that `"Quality"` renders more than twice as fast as `"Speed"`.